# Fill Combo box from DB with first custom item

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I Have a combo box in c# windows form which is being filled with Groups Names from SQL DB. While inserting new data user selects any group name which he/she want to make parent group if none selected new group would be simple not child. Here is what I want.

My expected combobox:

[image]

Here is my current code

```
private void fill_combobox(){
             main_class.sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT 
            GroupID,GroupName FROM Groups";
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = main_class.sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupName", typeof(string));        
            dt.Load(sqlReader);
            parent_group_combobox.ValueMember = "GroupID";
            parent_group_combobox.DisplayMember = "GroupName";                             
            parent_group_combobox.DataSource = dt;                             
            sqlReader.Close();
          }
```

And my expected code is something thing like

```
private void fill_combobox(){
             main_class.sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT 
            GroupID,GroupName FROM Groups";
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = main_class.sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupName", typeof(string));        
            dt.Load(sqlReader);
    parent_group_combobox.Items.Insert(0,"--None--");
            parent_group_combobox.ValueMember = "GroupID";
            parent_group_combobox.DisplayMember = "GroupName";                             
            parent_group_combobox.DataSource = dt;                             
            sqlReader.Close();
          }
```

Comment: Why don't you add the None item to your dt DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add "None" to the DataTable before loading the content from database:

```
...
dt.Rows.Add(0, "None");
dt.Load(sqlReader);
...
```